# How to download multiple pods

Tags: xcode8

NewBie here. I am not sure how to download multiple pods into my xcode project.

1) I have installed CocoaPods.

I have create a pod file for the first time to download a pod.

below is the pod file :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

2) How to download the next pod?

I have to use the **SAME pod file** and delete the previous content and enter the following new pod detail?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0'
end
```

a) Is this correct?  I just want to make sure I do not corrupt the file.

b) can I enter all the pod in one pod file?

Thanks.

-- Update--

```
1st Pod :

target '<Your Target Name>' do
        pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    end

to download the next pod.

Just replace the 'Alamfire','~> 4.4' with pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        platform :ios, ‘9.0’
    use_frameworks!
    def pods
        pod 'SVProgressHUD'
        pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.6'
        pod 'Alamofire’
        pod ‘AlamofireImage’, ‘3.2.0’
        pod 'SDWebImage',  '~>3.8'
        pod ‘SAConfettiView’, :git => ‘https://github.com/gokhanakkurt/SAConfettiView.git’, :branch => ‘swift3’
    end

    target “<Your Target Name>” do
        pods
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: can I download one by one using the same pod file? As I am a bit confused on the Post_install where SWIFT_VERSION ='3.0' ? swift version now is 4.0? and alamofire '~> 4.4'

Comment: means you want to add same pod file but with different version? right?

Comment: Use the same pod file with DIFFERENT pod detail. I delete the previous pod detail and enter a new pod detail and do a pod install.

Comment: if you add only new pod file and remove old one than why are you deleting all content? just add new one or replace it.

Comment: if you change only version of podifle than its automatically update with newer version. Thats it!

Comment: See my update, is this correct? 1) Change the pod name in the pod file to download the next pod. 2) To upgrade the pod version to 8 say, 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0'  change to, 'JTAppleCalendar,'~>8.0'

Comment: 2) JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0' change to, 'JTAppleCalendar,'~>8.0'  it updates your new version .

Comment: In your podfile pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4' ,than you are replacing it pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0, and than you are updates the version 'JTAppleCalendar,'~>8.0'. After completing all three steps in your project 'JTAppleCalendar,'~>8.0' podifle files will be there.